# Make Eclipse Content Assist continue to suggest "used" options as the first option

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

When I use `List.add()` once in a block of code, if I try to use it again it then Eclipse Content Assist will suggest `addAll()` even though it's a 0.7% chance, seemingly just because `add()` has been used.

[image]

Is there a way to make it so that the "used" tag doesn't affect Content Assist? It's really frustrating when I need `add()` more than once and it keeps giving me `addAll()`.